# How to specify a two dimensional array as custom tag attribute type?

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

When I create a custom tag I get an error:

> Unable to find setter method for attribute: atribut_1

Setter exists: `private Boolean[][] atribut_1;`

```
public void setAtribut_1(Boolean[][] atribut_1) {
    this.atribut_1 = atribut_1;
}
```

I have set the type of attribute in `.tld` file as `<type>java.lang.Boolean</type>`

Where is problem?

Comment: Please do not tag questions about custom tags with JSTL. That's not the same. JSTL is an existing and standard JSP taglib. To learn more about JSTL, read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 2):

The type of `java.lang.Boolean` is not the same as `java.lang.Boolean[][]` which you have there. As you have declared the taglib, it's expecting a setter of the following signature:

```java
public void setAtribut_1(Boolean atribut_1) {
    this.atribut_1 = atribut_1;
}
```

You need to fix the `<type>` attribute of the taglib declaration:

```xml
<type>java.lang.Boolean[][]</type>
```

Comment: yes, it first what i edited when i get this error. It dont help

Comment: What container are you using? Try `java.lang.Boolean[]` or just `java.lang.Object` instead or perhaps just `boolean[][]` with a `setAtribut_1(boolean[][] atribut_1)`.

Comment: Tomcat 7.0 . Both Boolean and Object dont help... I forget to say, that i always get with other errors the  "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp" exception. I.e. if i push F5 for refresging the browser, the TOmcat always rotate the errors - sometimes show me "NoSetMethod" exception, sometimes show ClassNotFoundException. Thank you for helping